# I can't open RQT

Tags: rqt, qt, rqt-gui

I just went through [these instructions](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html#install-qt5) to get ROS2 installed on my Windows laptop. Now I am trying to run the [turtlesim](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Introducing-Turtlesim/Introducing-Turtlesim.html) tutorial.

However, I can't open `rqt` as I am getting a bunch of import errors:

```
PySide2/__init__.py: Unable to import shiboken2 from C:\dev\ros2_iron\Scripts, C:\ci\ws\install\lib\python3.8\dist-packages, C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages, C:\Python38\python38_d.zip, C:\Python38\DLLs, C:\Python38\lib, C:\Python38, C:\Python38\lib\site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Scripts\rqt-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('rqt-gui==1.3.3', 'console_scripts', 'rqt')())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rqt_gui\main.py", line 94, in main
    sys.exit(Main().main())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rqt_gui\main.py", line 62, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\qt_gui\main.py", line 418, in main
    from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from python_qt_binding.binding_helper import loadUi  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 282, in <module>
    _select_qt_binding(
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 123, in _select_qt_binding
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find Qt binding (looked for: 'pyqt', 'pyside'):
  ImportError for 'pyqt': No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 113, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 158, in _load_pyqt
    _named_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 138, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'

  ImportError for 'pyside': No module named 'shiboken2.shiboken2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 113, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 190, in _load_pyside
    _named_import('PySide2.%s' % module_name)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\python_qt_binding\binding_helper.py", line 138, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 58, in _setupQtDirectories
    import shiboken2
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .shiboken2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shiboken2.shiboken2'
```

Seems something is wrong with `Qt`, but I have no clue what. I installed `Qt` as instructed.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! You need to install PyQt5.

Comment: Will give that a try once I'm back home. However, for the time being I was able to get everything working using docker. Will probably stick to docker anyway.

Comment: Oh, I just checked and I had pyqt5 installed already.